# Как устранить кучу дублей в OPENCART?

Tags: ооп, веб-программирование, opencart, php

Есть интернет-магазин realsila.ru и там куча дублей страниц, то есть бренды расположены в другом разделе, и там другие ссылки на товары, на главной тоже иные ссылки в хитах, акциях и т.д. Как устранить все эти дубли в интернете не нашел информации. Нужно чтобы ссылки с брендов товаров были одинаковые с товарами категорий, а как это сделать не знаю. Если кто делал, подскажите, пожалуйста, или сошлитесь на источник.

Answer (score 1):

В настройках магазина выберете модуль ЧПУ SeoPro и дублей не должно быть. Проверьте, чтобы название htacces файла было таким .htaccess, а не htaccess.txt или каким-то другим. И выставьте настройки как на скриншоте:

[image]